# JS Dynamically added fields - delete button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem is that then I add some input fields dynamically, the on click action which should delete the added row is not working. I know that click action has to use .on but it didn't helped. Any ideas?

Here is the .js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.eventsRowsWrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.eventsRows', this);

        $(".addEventButton", $(this)).on('click', function() {
            //console.log(jsFrontend.data.get('Planning.test'));
            //$('.multi-event:first-child').clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').attr('id', '');
            $($wrapper).append('<div class="form-group multi-event controls form-inline"> <input name="date[]" maxlength="255" type="text" placeholder="Data" class="datepickerClass form-control sortable ui-sortable" size="20"> <button type="button" style="float: none" class="close deleteEventButton">&times;</button></div>');
            $(".datepickerClass").datepicker();
            $('.sortable').sortable();
        });

        $('.multi-event').on('click', '.deleteEventButton', function() {
                if ($('.multi-event', $wrapper).length > 1){
                $(this).parent('.multi-event').remove();
            }
        });
    });

 });
```

And .html:

```
<div class="eventsRowsWrapper">
    <div class="eventsRows sortable">
        <div class="form-group multi-event controls form-inline">
            <input name="date[]" maxlength="255" type="text" placeholder="Data" class="datepickerClass form-control sortable ui-sortable" size="20">
            <button type="button" style="float: none" class="close deleteEventButton">&times;</button>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sharp addEventButton" type="button" name="addEvent">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Add event
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osmgs8gm/7/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
$('.multi-event').on('click', '.deleteEventButton', function() {
```

write:

```
$(document).on('click', '.multi-event .deleteEventButton', function() {
```

You are trying to attach an handler on something that does not exist in the dom yet.

Comment: or using closest static container `'.eventsRows'`